# Random walk with reflection and skips in linear system

Tags: markov-chains, random-walk

Let's take a case of simple and linear Random walk (0, 1...n) with only one absorbing state n and reflecting state -1, which we can define as:
P (move right at state i) = 1/2 and P (moving left at state i) = 1/2
I know that the expected hitting time at state n, starting at 0 is n<sup>2</sup> , which can be derived using recursive equation:
E<sub>i</sub> = 1/2 + 1/2 * (1 + E<sub>i-1</sub> + E<sub>i</sub>)
where E<sub>i</sub> is the expected hitting time at state i.
But, what will happen if we change the transition probabilities as follows:
1. At any intermediate state i, walker can jump directly to state n with probability p.
2. The transition probabilities of left and right will be modified to (1-p)/2 each.
This problem is similar to Random re-wiring problem discussed in *Collective dynamics of ‘small-world’ net-works* by *Duncan J. Watts and Steven H. Strogatz* .
What is the best way to model this case, and how can we compute the expected time to get absorbed.

Comment: The hitting time of n is roughly 1/p, the idea being that, with great probability if n is large, one hits n by a direct jump from some state i to state n rather than by (1-p)/2 steps.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Did Yes, it should be 1/p intuitively, but is there a mathematical proof behind that?

Comment: This hitting time is $T_p=\min(G_p,T)$ where $G_p$ is geometric with parameter $p$ and independent of $T$ the first hitting time of $n$ by the random walk with no jump. Since $T\geqslant n$, $\min(G_p,n)\leqslant T_p\leqslant G_p$ hence $$\frac1p-\frac1p(1-p)^{n}-n(1-p)^{n-1}\leqslant E(T_p)\leqslant\frac1p.$$

Comment: @Did I think you derived your expression by computing $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i^2 +1) (1-p)^{i^2} p$ < $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (i + 1) (1-p)^i p $ for large n. Though I agree with the inequality, but the expression in itself seems erroneous because we didn't consider retracts from any intermediate state, which makes $\sum_{i=0}^n (i^2 +1) (1-p)^{i^2} p$ incorrect. If you evaluated it in a different way, please share your process. I also need to compare the case for smaller values of n, which makes the calculations trivial to the problem.

Comment: @AdityaVirmani "My process" is there for all to see and is based on the rigorous identity $T_p=\min(G_p,T)$.